# What is the difference between _main and _blank tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I tried it but both shows similar work i.e. it opens new tab but what is the main difference between them.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="https://youtube.com" target="_main"> Click here to go to youtube</a>
 <br>
 <a href="https://yahoo.com" target="_main"> Click here to go to yahoo</a>
</body>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp  Go though the link it might help you. Go to the Attribute Values

Comment: Are you sure that _main is valid? Can you show a reference to this type?

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp the syntax section ```<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">```. The framename can be any frame name, if it exists

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `_main` is not an actual attribute for HTML hyperlinks. You may notice that `_anytext` would also open the link in a new tab, but is not an official attribute. Use `_blank` for this case.

Here are the accepted attributes, listed at w3schools:

_self - Default. Opens the document in the same window/tab as it was clicked 
_blank - Opens the document in a new window or tab 
_parent - Opens the document in the parent frame 
_top - Opens the document in the full body of the window

Comment: Check w3cschools, _main is a valid value for target.

Comment: I don't know where you are seeing this, but both links that the other answer provided did not contain _main as a valid target, nor do any other well-known sources.

Comment: See the specification https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp ```<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">```. The framename here is any name of an existing frame. You click the link ad it will be opened in the frame with specified name, which can be _main, _hello, _read_w3schools

Answer (score 0):

`_main` is not an `HTML` attribute, for opening your specified link in a new tab use `_blank`.

```
<a href="https://youtube.com" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
<a href="https://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
```

**FMI**: Visit the below link:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-a-target-html-attribute-explained/

Comment: _main is a valid value for target. Cherk your links.